# Cantor's diagonal argument on the countability of reals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, real-numbers

My understanding:

> Countability is defined as the ability to enumerate a set on the natural numbers (form some injective map between the set in question and $\Bbb{N}$, and an countably infinite set would be a bijection).
> Cantor's Diagonal Argument defines an arbitrary enumeration of the set $(0,1)$ with $\Bbb{N}$ and constructs a number in $(1,0)$ which cannot be defined by any arbitrary map. This constructed number is formed along the diagonal.

My question: 
I want to construct an enumeration with the following logic: 
Consider $n \in \Bbb{N}$ we multiply *n* by $10^{-1 \times(\text{number of trailing zeros + 1})}$ , so we end up with $1 \to 0.1$, $100\to 0.001$, etc...
Why is this not a correct enumeration of $(0,1)$ by $\Bbb{N}$?

My thoughts:
Is the enumeration wrong due to the non-terminating nature of $\Bbb{R}$? I know that the natural numbers are terminating and the reals are not, but I don't completely understand what that implies.

Comment: What natural number maps to $1/3$?

Comment: A potentially subtle point: cantor's argument does not _define_ an arbitrary enumeraron of $(0,1)$. Moreover, it does not construct a number that is not hit by an arbitrary map. What it does is take any function $f : \mathbb N \to (0,1)$ and returns an $x^* \in (0,1)$ such that for all $n$ $f(n) \neq x^*$. Importantly, this $x^*$ depends on $f$!